# GROUP BY not returning correct totals

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have this query which I have been messing with and cannot seem to see what to change in order to receive the results I want.

I want to sum sales by `Emp_ID` by day, but only sum the ones over $10000 for that day. Below is what I currently have

```
SELECT
    Emp_ID,
    sum(SaleA+SaleB) as TotalSales,
    sum(SaleA+SaleB-CommA-CommB) as TSalesAftComm,
    count(Emp_ID) as NumOfSales,
    SaleDate
FROM
    Sales (nolock)
WHERE
    SaleDate>='2014-03-15 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    SaleDate, Emp_ID
HAVING
    sum(SaleA+SaleB) > 10000
ORDER BY
    SaleDate
```

I know that in my select and group by (Emp_ID) it will group by date and also Emp_ID for that date. It seems if I remove the Emp_ID in the SELECT and GROUP BY area it adds all sales for that day even the ones below $10000.

Below are the results I get

```
Emp_ID | TotalSales | TSalesAftComm | NumOfSales | SaleDate
   1      10897.65      10000             6        2014-03-15 00:00:00.000
   1      18897.65      17800             8        2014-03-15 00:00:00.000
   2      10797.65      10000             5        2014-03-15 00:00:00.000
   1      10897.65      10000             6        2014-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to see the results as

```
       | TotalSales | TSalesAftComm | NumOfSales | SaleDate
          40592.95      37800             19        2014-03-15 00:00:00.000
          10897.65      10000              6        2014-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

Thank you for any help or direction you can provide.

Comment: Do you have some sample table contents for which you'd want the result displayed that you could add to the question?

Comment: I would like to see the results as the last table results I listed if possible

Comment: Yes, but what is the content of the table for which you would like this to be the answer? You're giving the answer, not the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have SQL Server 2000 to test with, but you *should* be able to get it done using a plain subquery, something like;

```
SELECT SUM(TotalSales) TotalSales, SUM(TSalesAftComm) TSalesAftComm,
       SUM(NumOfSales) NumOfSales, SaleDate
FROM (
  SELECT
      Emp_ID,
      sum(SaleA+SaleB) as TotalSales,
      sum(SaleA+SaleB-CommA-CommB) as TSalesAftComm,
      count(Emp_ID) as NumOfSales,
      SaleDate
  FROM Sales (nolock)
  WHERE SaleDate>='2014-03-15 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY SaleDate, Emp_ID
  HAVING
      sum(SaleA+SaleB) > 10000
) z
GROUP BY SaleDate
ORDER BY SaleDate
```

Comment: This one seems to have summed all the sales, even the ones below 10k for that day. I was pretty confident this one was looking promissing

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at actual data/schema, and looking at your expected results, what happens if you try this (look at the group by section, showing group by TotalSales; employee id removed too)?

```
SELECT
    sum(SaleA+SaleB) as TotalSales,
    sum(SaleA+SaleB-CommA-CommB) as TSalesAftComm,
    count(Emp_ID) as NumOfSales,
    SaleDate
FROM
    Sales (nolock)
WHERE
    SaleDate>='2014-03-15 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    TotalSales
HAVING
    sum(SaleA+SaleB) > 10000
ORDER BY
    SaleDate
```

Comment: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause. is the error I get on this

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't mean to put sum there.   I was just editing my post when you commented.  lol

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid column name 'TotalSales'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid column name 'TotalSales'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid column name 'TotalSales'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid column name 'TotalSales'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid column name 'TotalSales'. is now the error :(

Comment: `GROUP BY SUM(SaleA+SaleB)`. By the way, do you have any NULLs in either of those columns? Because if you do, you might want to make that `SUM(CASE WHEN SaleA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SaleA END + CASE WHEN SaleB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SaleB END)`. (Unfortunately, there is no `COALESCE()` in SqlServer 2000.)

Comment: Ok, i'd have to build some test data and try, but as I look at it, my query will most likely look a lot like @JoachimIsaksson's post.   It my be an option to his post a try.

Comment: Thank you all for your input it help me greatly and now have the correct answer

Comment: No problem.  I'd like to see your official results (maybe post as an edit in your question?).

@outisnihil, actually, there is a [coalesce() in sql server 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: @TinyHaitian, well, looks like you're right about `COALESCE()` I stand corrected, but can't edit an old comment.

Comment: That's what this site is for, right? keep ourselves up to date and help others.   :)

Answer (score 1):

You say, "I want to sum Sales by Emp_ID by day, but only sum the ones over $10000. Below is what I currently have."

I read that as you only want to include sales over 10k. In other words you want to sum the sales > 10k and ignore <=10. If that is the case then you need to remove

```
HAVING sum(SaleA+SaleB) > 10000
```

and instead add to the where clause

```
WHERE SaleDate>='2014-03-15 00:00:00'
  AND SaleA+SaleB > 10000
```

If you mean something else, please edit the question to clarify and I'll take another look.

Comment: Perhaps I am asking it incorrectly. I want all sales for the day summed and if that sum is > 10000 then include in to my query